# post_filter producing different results than a normal filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I adapted a query I had to apply the filters after aggregations but now I'm seeing different items in the result set. It's almost as if the items with ["filters"]["bool"]["should"] are now being ignored entirely.

This works properly:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
          ...
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                    "term": {
                        "any_pickup_options": true
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "local_delivery": true
                    }
                }],
                "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "active": true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what is failing:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
          ...
        }
    }
},
"post_filter": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "term": {
                "any_pickup_options": true
            }
        }, {
            "term": {
                "local_delivery": true
            }
        }],
        "must": [{
            "term": {
                "active": true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

The ["post_filters"]["bool"]["must"] constraints are taken into account. But the result set doesn't contain any items which have `any_pickup_options` or  `local_delivery` set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. You have to specify minimum_should_match in a filter context.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html